# javascript/typescript object null check

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a difference in performance while doing null checks in below 2 ways -

```
if (!someObject) {
   // dosomething
}
```

vs

```
if (someObject != null) {
   // dosomething
}
```

Comment: If your question is about performance, why don't you just measure it?

Comment: @Yousuf Read https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js at "4.Conditional Evaluation"

Comment: @wf9a5m75 Thanks for the link, looks like a good resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!someObject` checks for all falsy values.

```
Not ( empty string, undefined, null, 0, false) - will all pass the condition
```

where as the first condition only checks for null.

```
 if (someObject !== null) {
    console.log('falsey');
 }

 someObject = null;      // no message in console
 someObject = '';        // falsey
 someObject = undefined; // falsey
 someObject = 0;         // falsey
 someObject = false;     // falsey
```

**Falsey check**

```
if (!someObject) {
    console.log('falsey');
 }

 someObject = null;      // no message in console
 someObject = '';        // no message in console
 someObject = undefined; // no message in console
 someObject = 0;         // no message in console
 someObject = false;     // no message in console
```

Comment: Since !someObject is evaluating all truthy values, does it mean it is not as efficient  when  I need to check only for null's?

Comment: Since it is just a simple check, the performance with be negligible for both the cases,

Comment: okay, I thought so. My colleague told me it is not efficient, so I was wondering.

Comment: @Yousuf Your colleague's concern was probably more a combination of performance as well as your dependence on implicit typecasting to evaluate for a null or undefined value. (I am your colleague)

Comment: BTW, Benchmark.js says it's about 16% difference (Chrome, `someObject = {}`). As long as someObject is not null. In case it's null, second option is faster: https://jsbench.me/tiizafwdy4

Answer (score 0):

to properly check for a null you'd have to write:

```
  if(!someobject && typeof someobject!== "object")
```

Ideally `typeof null` should not return "object"

The Types and Grammar chapter in [You Don't Know JS](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch01.html) mentions:

> this original bug in JS has persisted for nearly two decades, and will likely never be fixed because there’s so much existing web content that relies on its buggy behavior that “fixing” the bug would create more “bugs” and break a lot of web software.